# Django - Annotate with count across ManytoMany relationships (refrase)

Tags: django, django-annotate

[Django - Annotate with count across ManytoMany relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52733085/django-annotate-with-count-across-manytomany-relationships/58894595?noredirect=1#comment104054026_58894595)

I am not able to find the way to annotate a queryset with a count of how many times an element is used in a many-to-many relationship.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    [...]
    # Profile can have multiple roles
    roles = models.ManyToManyField('Role', blank=True)
    [...]

class Role(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300)
    [...]
```

For example I would have 5 roles:

- Role1
- Role2
- Role3
- Role4
- Role5

And 2 profiles with following roles assigned:

- Profile1

  - Role 1
  - Role 2
- Profile2

  - Role 1
  - Role 3
  - Role 4

I need to have the oposite than @ha-duy:

```
Profile: name, role_count=2
Profile: name, role_count=3
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Idea:

In the same view where you update the rolls loop through the many to many fields and return the length. then update the model appropriately.

Better Idea:

create a custom save method for the profile model so that every time .save() is called it will calculate the number of roles and update that field. 
more info on that here. 
[custom save method on model - django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456913/custom-save-method-on-model-django)

Maybe this will help because it won't be persistent in the DB but will give you the info:

```
class Test(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=10,)
category = models.ManyToManyField(cats)

def __str__(self):
    x = self.category.all()
    y = len(x) 
    return 'this is an item count ' + str(y)
```

or if you want it in object form:

add this to the model.

```
    def dataBlock(self):
       x = self.category.all()
       y = len(x) 
       return {
           'name': self.name,
           'cat_length': y,
       }
```

Comment: Thanks @cr-python for your response, I know that it is not in the problem description 
but it I am looking for something that do not persist in the DB. The roles count is an example, I need to solve the same case with other columns like get the description of the longer role name.

Comment: I followed your "better idea" of saving a calculated value on the data base and it is working. THANK!
I am updating the values when a m2m_changed signal is called